# Castle windsor: Register generics with more than one items

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, castle

I have a generic interface defined like this -

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity, TDbContextType>
    where TEntity : class
    where TDbContextType : IDbContextType
```

This interface is implemented by a class like this -

```
 public class GenericRepository<TEntity,TDbContextType> 
    : IGenericRepository<TEntity, TDbContextType> 
    where TEntity : class 
    where TDbContextType: IDbContextType
```

I tried the following for registering this interface and implementation with castle -

```
   _container.Register(Component.For(typeof (IGenericRepository<>))
       .ImplementedBy(typeof (GenericRepository<>))
       .LifestylePerWcfOperation());
```

But it fails at compile time Saying "incorrect number of paramters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails to compile because you specific generic types with one single parameter, but you defined types with two parameters.

So you should use `IGenericRepository<,>` and `GenericRepository<,>` instead of `IGenericRepository<>` and `GenericRepository<>`.